# why i cannot compile simple project by dev c

Tags: c

I don't know why cannot compile simple project below by dev.

> **error**: Project1.exe has stopped working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n,d;
    while(1){
        printf("enter number");
        scanf("%d",n);
        d=n%10;
        while(d!=0){
            n=n/10;
            printf("%d",d);
            d=n%10;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just about any tutorial or book (good and bad) should have shown you how to use `scanf` and that you need to use the address-of operator `&` for almost all argument types (except strings). Perhaps you should go back to your tutorial or book and read it more thoroughly?

Comment: The problem would've been obvious if you compiled with warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the error that you got is not a compile, it's a run time error.
Second, it's happen when the run arrive to the line of `scanf`. This function required the variavbles address to put the value in.

Replace this:

```
scanf("%d", n);
```

With this:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh yeah, tnx alot

Answer (score 1):

For one, your project does compile, since you get a run time error.

The run time error occurs because you are not using `scanf` correctly. The arguments to scanf after the format string should be pointers to the variables.

I don't know which compiler you are using, but any fairly modern compiler would have given you compiler warnings about this, e.g. here's Clang's output:

```
apa.c:9:20: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%d",n);
               ~~  ^
```

Changing this into `scanf("%d",&n);` makes your program work.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf